# Cannot find symbol class MyActivity_ in Android project use AndroidAnnotation

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-annotations

In my project I use AndroidAnnotation but I got errors that couldn't generated subclass by AA.
My build.gradle file like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-apt'
def AAVersion = '3.2'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apt {
    arguments {
        androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
        resourcePackageName 'com.mycompanyspace.mycompany'
    }
}
tasks.findByPath(":facebook:androidJavadocs").enabled = false
android {
    signingConfigs {
        build_release {
            keyAlias 'publish'
            keyPassword 'mycompanyspace'
            storeFile file('address of my keystore')
            storePassword 'mycompanyspace'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mycompanyspace.mycompany"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 28
        versionName "1.0"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.build_release
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            ext.enableCrashlytics = false
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        publish {
            applicationId = "com.mycompanyspace.mycompany"
            versionName "2.0.3"
        }
        develop {
            applicationId = "com.mycompanyspace.mycompanydev"
            versionName "2.0d"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.17'
    //compile project(':android-volley')
    apt 'org.androidannotations:androidannotations:3.2'
    compile files('libs/androidannotations-api-3.2.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile files('libs/simple.facebook-2.2.jar')
    compile files('khandroid-httpclient-4.2.3.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
    compile project(':imageViewLibrary')
    compile files('libs/ormlite-android-4.48.jar')
    compile files('libs/ormlite-core-4.48.jar')
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.20.0'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.20.0'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-gson:1.20.0'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-calendar:v3-rev125-1.20.0'
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.9.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/khandroid-httpclient-4.2.3.jar')
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.1.4'
    //compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
    compile project(':libfont')
    compile project(':facebook')
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.4.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile project(':CircleAnimationlibrary')
    compile 'org.apmem.tools:layouts:1.9@aar'
    //compile project(':AnimationLibrary')
    compile project(':AnimationLib')
    compile 'org.piwik.sdk:piwik-sdk:0.0.3'
    compile 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:1.+'
    compile 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.+'
}
```

I have try newest AA version, change gradle version.
Does anyone has any suggestion for this case?

UPDATE 1 - BUILD LOG:
@WonderCsabo

```
D:\DuAnFreelancer\JAMJA-ANDROID-develop\app\src\main\java\com\jamjavn\view\ListviewRelatedDeal.java
Error:(22, 8) error: class ListViewRelatedDeal is public, should be declared in a file named ListViewRelatedDeal.java
D:\DuAnFreelancer\JAMJA-ANDROID-develop\app\src\main\java\com\jamjavn\adapter\BrandDetailPagerAdapter.java
Error:(10, 28) error: cannot find symbol class ListStoreFragment_
Error:(12, 28) error: cannot find symbol class MarketFragment_

Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 5.146 secs
Information:101 errors
Information:2 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: Your Gradle files look fine although you could depend on the androidannotations api jar from Maven Central instead of the local libs folder. Can you share the whole build log?

Comment: This is screenshot when I try to run my project
http://prnt.sc/c2nzkq

Comment: You shared the wrong link I think. Anyway, instead of adding a screenshot, copy the build log from the Gradle console.

Comment: @WonderCsabo I added build log, 101 errors in my prj but I think two of them could say for all

Comment: There are lots of errors, you should fix them before trying to find what is problem with annotation processing.

Comment: @wonderCsabo all of them are also AA errors, the left 99 errors have errors log: Cannot find symbol class MyClassess_

Comment: Please attach the full build log after fixing non AA errors.